# ので with requests

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, politeness

I was consulting my grammar book (A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar), when I came upon the following passage (page 323):

[image]

Now this is all well and good. But it's a bit conflicting with an explanation in A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar, in the section about ので (these books are in a series, by the same authors). Here's the relevant explanation (page 329-330):

[image]

This section is rather explicit that ので is unusable with requests, advice, suggestions etc. My Japanese teacher has also said that ので is unusable with advice.

I suppose then the question is, what is the truth? Is the original example sentence natural? Grammatical? Is there a deeper conclusion to draw here? Maybe から is inappropriate in such a polite request? Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: Well, that's what you get leveling up from _Basic_ to _Intermediate_. Jokes aside, this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4715/

Comment: I always wonder why it's so hard to find duplicates...

Comment: As mentioned, it's beyond the basics, so take your time to digest. Let me share a list of [possibly related posts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89+%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7)