# 「から」「ので」「ーんで」など

Tags: grammar, word-choice

日本で大学に通っている留学生です。

基本的に普段友達と話す時は「から」、面接や先生へのメールなど敬語で話す時は「ので」を使っていますが、ある程度親しい目上の人（学校やバイト先の一個上の先輩など）と敬語で話す時に「ので」を使ってもおかしくないのでしょうか？

「から」は「ですます」形で使うと個人的には日本語的に正しくない感じがしますし、「ので」は書き言葉のような印象で、工夫したのが「んで」（例：私はさっき昼ご飯食べてきたんで、大丈夫です。）だったのですが、「んで」は砕けすぎているのではないかと心配してきました。

このように、公式の場ではなく、親しい目上の人と話す時に、砕けすぎず、同時に丁寧すぎない（書き言葉に聞こえない）一番無難な接続表現は何でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

「ので」と「んで」の使い分けについて。一個上の先輩なら、「んで」が砕けすぎているということは全くないと思います。仕事とは関係ないカジュアルな会話であれば、ほとんどの場合は「んで」で問題ありません。職場内でも、よほど気難しい上司と話すのでない限り、たいていの人は「んで」を使っていると思います。会話で「ので」が明らかに好まれるのは、店員が客に話す時など、かなりフォーマルな敬語を使う場面に限られます。

「ので」と「から」の使い分けについては、ネイティブスピーカーには非常に難しい問題です。日本人は全く考えず自然に使い分けており、個々の例を示されれば「これは自然で、これは不自然だ」と言えるのですが、その理由を論理的に説明できる人はほとんどいないと思います。少なくとも、「ですます体では『から』を使うな」というような単純な話ではありません。以下の既存の質問をご覧ください。

- [What are the differences between 〜ので and 〜から?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/411/5010)
- [When to use ～ので vs ～から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4715/5010)

Answer (score 0):

質問者の提示した２つの例を使って、相手によってどのように表現を使い分けるかを試してみました。
相手は、自分の先生、一つ年上の親しい先輩、そして、親しい後輩の３通りです。

結果は（１-１）から（２-３）に示すとおりですが、
（A）必ずしも「から」あるいは「ので」で使い分けているのでは無いようです。
（B）相手が目上｛めうえ｝であればあるほど、言葉[遣]{づか}いも大切ですが、それ以上に**状況説明が丁寧になる / 詳しくなる**ように思います。逆に言うと、相手が目下｛めした｝であるほど、状況説明が省略される傾向にあります。
（C）相手が目上であればあるほど、自分自身の判断も断定的でなくなるように思います。逆にいうと、相手が目下｛めした｝であるほど、自分自身の判断が断定的になるように思います。

（１-１）
先生！ 変な話ですが、日本に来て１年も経つのに敬語の使い方が良｛よ｝く分からないんです。実は、インターネットのあるサイトで「から」が良｛い｝いのか「ので」が良｛い｝いのか質問しました。いろいろな回答はありましたが、結局どれも納得できなかったように思います。
多分、私の質問の仕方が下手だった**から**でしょうか。

（１-２）
先輩！ 敬語の使い方が今一{いまひと}つ分からないので、インターネットのあるサイトで「から」が良｛い｝いのか「ので」が良｛い｝いのか質問したんですよ。結構いろいろな回答はありましたが、結局どれも納得できなかったですね。
質問の仕方が下手だった**から**ですかね。

（１-３）
敬語が[今一]{いまいち}分からないんで、インターネットのあるサイトで「から」が良｛い｝いのか「ので」が良｛い｝いのか聞いたんだ。回答は結構いろいろあったんだ。でも結局[今一]｛いまいち｝ピーンと来る回答はなかったな。質問の仕方がまずかった**から**かな。

---

（２-１）
A君！ これ食べる？
いいえ、結構です。さっき食堂で昼食｛ちゅうしょく｝食べてきました**ので**。

（２-２）
A！ これ食べる？
いや、結構です。さっき昼飯｛ひるめし｝食って来た**んで**。

（２-３）
先輩！ これ食べます？
いや、良{い}いよ。さっき昼飯｛ひるめし｝食って来た**んだ**。